# .htaccess rewriterules exclude directory

Tags: .htaccess

I made all my htaccess rewriterules but now I want to exclude all the directories and files from it. All hints regarding this htaccess are welcome, because I haven't got experience with rewrite rules...

I figured out that the RewriteCond will only work for the first rule that follows.
Thus how can I exclude all files and directories from all rules?

```
Allow from All
RewriteEngine on

SetEnv DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT true


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#One url parameter
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$ index.php?language=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?language=$1

#Two url parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2

#Three url parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&feed=$3&message=$3&page_number=$3&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&feed=$3&message=$3&page_number=$3&id=$3

#Four url parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)/$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&id=$3

#Five url parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&feed=$3&year=$4&month=$5
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/$ index.php?language=$1&page=$2&feed=$3&year=$4&month=$5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thus how can I exclude all files and directories from all rules?

I guess you mean:

> Thus how can I exclude all files and directories **THAT EXIST** from all rules?

Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .*  - [L]
```

Replace the first 2 `RewriteCond` lines with the above set.

Comment: Great, works perfectly!